# Server 2008 (not R2) Web Edition Max Local Users

Tags: windows-server-2008

Is there a limit to the number of local Users that can be created in Server 2008 Web Edition SP2? I know there used to be a limit on SBS servers but that may be due to the fact that you got AD within that licence.

The reason I'm asking is because I'm using WebsitePanel (formally DNP) to manage my servers which creates two local user accounts for every account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one - local security registry is not using a real database to my knowledge - but it is quite high, possibly in hundreds of thousands. Most problem may be the memory use if you ever run into that.

Comment: ah OK, but not limited to like 50 or 75 like SBS was?

Comment: No definitely not that low.

Comment: It is a technical, not a logical limit. Basically at one point the db turns tooo large.... which is where AD witha relational model starts to shine (and with the dedicated servers you can have then).